# Operator precedence and unary operators in irony

Tags: c#, parsing, irony

I'm having problems getting my grammar to work with unary operations. For instance, if I enter "-5/2" I get -(5/2), not (-5)/2 which I would like to get. In this particular case the difference does not matter, however, I still think fixing this is important for the grammar.

However, it's also important that 1-5/2 get's parsed as 1-(5/2) and not (1-5)/2.

Currently I have the following operator's registered:

```
        RegisterOperators(1, "||");
        RegisterOperators(2, "&&");
        RegisterOperators(3, "|");
        RegisterOperators(4, "^");
        RegisterOperators(5, "&");
        RegisterOperators(6, "==", "!=");
        RegisterOperators(7, "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "is");
        RegisterOperators(8, "<<", ">>");
        RegisterOperators(9, "+", "-");
        RegisterOperators(10, "*", "/", "%");
        RegisterOperators(11, "!");
        RegisterOperators(-1, "?");
        RegisterOperators(-2, "=", "+=", "-=", "*=", "/=", "%=", "&=", "|=", "^=", "<<=", ">>=");
```

The not operator already works as I want it to, however, the "+" and "-" kind of needs to be where they are in order to make sure that the "*", "/" and "%" is interpreted correctly. How should I solve this? Btw, if you need more of the grammar just let me know, I just figured I didn't need to drop more code here than necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying I figured out a solution:

```
UnaryExpr.Rule = ImplyPrecedenceHere(30) + LUnOp + Expr;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
UnaryExpr.Rule = LUnOp + Expr + ReduceHere();
```